# imap_headerinfo Address buffer overflow for more recipient address

Tags: php, imap, fatal-error, email-client

I have a download mail client tool using `php imap`. It is working for mails which is having less address (To,cc..). But for more address it is throwing an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  imap_headerinfo() [<a href='function.imap-headerinfo'>function.imap-headerinfo</a>]: Address buffer overflow
```

Could any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

This happens as a protection measure against using PHP scripts for spamming many different mail addresses.
You can't put that many addresses in the fields - you should rather send an email to each recipient individually.

Comment: Thats correct,but is there any workaround for this because it is working for download of mail from gmail server to my server.